# Fastener on 2017 VW Jetta won’t screw back in after replacing light bulbs

Tags: vw, tail-lights, fastener

I have a fastener that is screwed into the taillight for my 2017 Jetta. I successfully replaced a bulb but the screw won’t screw back in.

I confirmed it’s an issue with the screw as another screw from the other tail light was able to be screwed in. Anyone have any ideas of how to fix it short of replacing the part?

[pic of fastener](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TreKH.jpg)

[image]

[image]

Comment: A picture of the screw in question might be useful. You can amend your question to attach a picture using the little "picture" icon in the formatting box.

Comment: The picture was too big so I used an Imgur link instead.

Comment: The thread at the end is crossthreaded, replace it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you damaged the start of the thread - easy to do on plastic threads.

Dress the end of the thread with a small file and make sure it is clean, then it will normally go in.

Comment: I used a small filer and at the right angle was able to screw it in without the need for a new part. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @AdamS good for you well done.

Answer (score 0):

If chasing and dressing the threads (as Solar Mike suggests in his answer) doesn't work, go to a VW dealer and buy a replacement screw. The screw's design is unusual, so you won't find it in a hardware or auto parts shop.